# Customizing Bootstrap LESS input-append

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm customizing Bootstrap using LESS variables. I had success to certain extent. I'm stuck in form controls.

If I write the below, the button extension works well (btw, this is in jade),

```
        form
            div.input-append
                input.span2#appendedInput(type="text", placeholder="Email")
                button.btn(type="submit") Submit
```

it works well as below:

[image]

However, if I don't want to litter layout file with bootstrap variables and try the below it doesn't work.

layout.jade

```
div.email-action
                    input#appendedInput(type="text", placeholder="Email")
                    button(type="submit") Submit
```

layout.css

```
email-action{
    .input-append;
    input{
        .span(2);
    }
    button{
        .btn;
    }
}
```

It looks like:

[image]

How to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `email-action` selector is missing a `.` (should be `.email-action`). As it is, it's selecting an element rather than a class.